# Finding E(X) of gamma function

Tags: gamma-function

Show that $E(\varepsilon)={\alpha}m$ when gamma distribution function is given as

$$f(\varepsilon)=\frac{1}{{\alpha^m\Gamma(m)}}\varepsilon^{m-1}\text{exp}[-\frac{\varepsilon}{\alpha}]$$

I am so stuck with calculations of this. I am using the formula of $\Gamma(\alpha+1)=\alpha\Gamma(\alpha)$ but I can't get the required result. I am stuck while counting the integral at the part where I would already plug in the limits. I get something like this before plugging in the limits: $\frac{m\Gamma(m)e^\frac{1}{\alpha}}{\alpha\Gamma(m)}$.

Comment: You are computing $\frac{1}{\alpha^m \Gamma(m)} \int_0^\infty x^m \exp(-x/\alpha) dx$. Change variables to $u=x/\alpha$ and pull constants out. You should get a constant times $\Gamma(m+1)$. Then $\frac{\Gamma(m+1)}{\Gamma(m)}=m$ finishes the job.

Comment: I think I have nailed it, thank you.